# Cannot use function call as first argument in s-exp

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to use a function to return a function in common lisp. However, I've run into a strange situation I'd like explained.

This is what I want to do:

```
(defun makefun(x) ;1
  (lambda (z)
    (+ x z)))

((makefun 1) 2) ;2
```

This results in an illegal function call. However, the following are valid:

```
((lambda (z) (+ 1 z)) 2) ;3

(funcall (makefun 1) 2) ;4
```

Why can I not use makefun as in the first example? I'd expect the call in 2 to be evaluated so it would be equivalent to line 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If answered a similar question already on Stackoverflow. It's a duplicate. Would need to find it.

Anyway.

```
(defun makefun(x) ;1
  (lambda (z)
    (+ x z)))

((makefun 1) 2)
```

Common Lisp does not allow evaluation in the function position. It requires you to put a symbol or an actual lambda expression there.

Remember: Common Lisp has a separate *function namespace*. The *value namespace* is different. Here `MAKEFUN` returns a value and this value is not available in the function namespace.

There are only two syntactic ways to call a function:

```
(foo 1 2)
```

and

```
((lambda (a b) (list a b)) 1 2)
```

See [CLHS (Conses as Forms)](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm). Here we have a *Lambda Form*.

Adding the capability to write `((some-function-returning-function) 1 2)` would make function calling in Common Lisp more confusing:

- `(foo 1 2)` would use the function namespace
- `((some-function-returning-function) 1 2)` would use the value namespace

Answer (score 4):

Common Lisp has several different [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11877603/271324), and in [function forms](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_form), the [functional value](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_f.htm#functional_value) of the operator is used. Your `lambda` example works, because [lambda forms](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababd.htm) are a separate branch in the evaluation rules. You can just google for "Common Lisp namespaces" "Lisp-1 vs. Lisp-2" for more details, and there are quite a few questions and answers here [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/271324) that cover those topics.

But, to answer your particular question, use [`funcall`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm) (you can also take a look at [`apply`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm)):

```
(funcall (makefun 1) 2)
```